# Appending target="_blank" to links in an iframe without using <body onload>

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, iframe

I'm trying to change the links in an iframe to load in a new window instead of the iframe itself. Currently I use this code in `head`:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var oIFrame = document.getElementById("iframeID");
    var oDoc = (oIFrame.contentWindow || oIFrame.contentDocument);
    if(oDoc.document) oDoc = oDoc.document;
    var links = oDoc.getElementsByTagName("a");
    for(var i=0; i<links.length; i++) { links[i].target="_blank"; }
});
```

However, the code above is triggered before the iframe is fully loaded with its contents. I know this code would work if it's triggered in the body onload attribute, but I'd like to avoid that method and implement it in a function or a file instead.

Answer (score 2):

Try

```
$("#iframeid").load(function(){
    // your code
});
```

Comment: @CincauHangus; No, this triggers when the iframe content is fully loaded. This should work.

Answer (score 0):

Have a go with:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var oIFrame = document.getElementById("iframeID");
    var oDoc = (oIFrame.contentWindow || oIFrame.contentDocument);
    if(oDoc.document) oDoc = oDoc.document;
    $(oDoc).ready(function(){
        var links = oDoc.getElementsByTagName("a");
        for(var i=0; i<links.length; i++) { links[i].target="_blank"; }
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You could set a timeout function periodically checking if

```
iframe.document.readyState == 'complete'
```